# Android - dp units on layouts -look like bad idea?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Android developers site,and most of you,Push everybody to use dp units on their layouts,

I can understand this approach if you using different layout for different densities,but when my requires is one layout.xml ,and one drawable folder,it is make no sense to me to use it,
because it is NOT preserve proportion.

It seems weird to me that there is no simple way to preserve proportion for all devices.

Just help you to understand my point.
1.make any layout with view inside it
2.set the sizes on dp as Android advise you to do
3.and then check it on the eclipse graphical view of your XML.

It looks way way different between different size devices.
Button with width of 15 dp look like 10 times bigger in 640*480 devices then Tablets.
So what's the point?

I understand all the math of conversion between dp and pixel with density,
but i looking for simple way to preserver the proportion on my layout,without define others for others densities.

The only way that i find to help is using android:weightsum,
But it can not use for margins and other settings.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can always use your **values** folder and implements the exact `dp` size for each of different device densities, so you wont create different layout on different density.

Tablet and handheld devices will never have the same sizes that is where the different layout folders are created to let the developers design on different devices.

I would recommend a different layout design on tablet and handheld devices which most apps applies.

Answer (score 1):

Think of dp units as referring to actual size (like cm and inches). So something that is 250dp will look (for example) about 1 inch on a phone, but also roughly 1 inch on a tablet. No matter the size and resolution of the device, it will always be about 1 inch.

Why is it done this way? Well basically it is the Android creative vision that you won't simply scale your app from a handheld screen to a tablet sized screen. This is why they don't allow you to specify heights and widths as % of screen size. The one small exception is layout_weight in LinearLayout.

You may agree or disagree with their vision, but that's the reality.